# Cannot upload to new local repo on Bitbucket remote repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I need to start a new repo on Bitbucket, I created one on Bitbucket and on my local PC I created a folder and is has files in it. I am using Sourcetree but I cannot figure out how to link the two via Soucetree, so I am using some notes that I made when I used to do this command line.

Well all goes well, as I remembered it, until I issued the last command `git push -u origin --all` this "should" push all my local files up to the remote repo. However, it gives me the error:

`Unauthorized`
`fatal: Could not read from remote respository.`
`Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the respository exists`

So I look at the email and username on my local machine and they appear to matc and those credentials own the repo. So I don't know what to do next. There are not SSH keys that I saw in the settings in the repo and I was working on another project a few weeks ago just fine.

One thing to note is that I think my IP address changed as I have been getting notifications that a few services I use "don't recognize my device" could that be in the way?

Comment: You can verify if you SSH is setup correctly with this `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`. it should print `logged in as <user> You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled`

Comment: OH it says the deploy key is to another repo

Answer (score 0):

Check first the remote in your local repository, in command-line:

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git remote -v
```

The key part is to see if you are using:

- an HTTPS URL like `https://bitbucket.org/<me>/<myrepo>`
- or an SSH URL like `git@bitbucket.org:<me>/<myrepo>`

Then you can start checking your credentials (username/password or SSH keys)

---

Since it is an SSH URL, it is important to check your $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub is correctly registered to your BitBucket account.
See "[Bitbucket: Set up an SSH key](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html)"

But that will work only for the owner of the repository, or a user declared as collaborator on that repository.

Comment: $ git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.org:real-crypto/tradetriggers.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:real-crypto/tradetriggers.git (push)

Comment: @illcrx I have edited my answer. Are you `real-crypto` on Bitbucket? Or are you declared as a collabortor on that `real-crypto/tradetriggers.git` repository?

Comment: Yes that is me, I just double checked.

Comment: @illcrx OK then: create a register an SSH private/public key, and this should work.